# Probability the pedestrian has to wait 3 time epochs to cross the street.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Setting**

A pedestrian can cross a street at epochs k = 0, 1, 2, . . . . The event that a car will be passing the crossing at any given epoch is described by a Bernoulli trial with success probability p. The pedestrian can cross the street only if there will be no car passing over the next three epochs. Find the probability that the pedestrian has to wait exactly k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 epochs.

**Solution**

I'm expressing $k=3$ only as a spot check. My argument is

$$\Pr[k=3] = q^4\left(\binom{3}{1}pq^2 + \binom{3}{2}p^2 q + \binom{3}{3}p^3q^0   \right)$$

where q = 1 - p.

Since If the pedestrian is crossing at k=3, then we have the intersection of two sets of events: (1) k={3,4,5,6} have no cars, and(2) k={0,1,2} may have 1,2, or 3 cars passing by.

Comment: The approach looks correct to me. The problem statement is slightly unclear: when it says three next epochs, does it exclude the current? You are interested in $k=3$ and require that epochs $4,5 $ and $6$ are car free. But you also seem to require that epoch $3$ is also car free, i.e., four epochs in total. Under these assumptions, your approach seems correct.

Comment: Yeah I was unclear too, so I assumed a pedestrian cannot cross the street at the same time that a car is also on the street. But thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I interpret the $k=3$ event as: a car comes at epochs $0,1,2$ but not at epoch $3$ and we don't care about epochs after $3$. And the $k=0$ event simply as: no car at epoch $0$.